# Fetching Data from a Realtime Firestore Document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have seen similar questions and answers being solved with the StreamBuilder widget.

In my case when I am implementing it my code does not await to fetch the data and just moves on (in my case, the app jumps to the next page). Thus, do I need the build a StreamBuilder Widget or is there a simple method that could work and fetch the data in realtime?

I noticed that I did not use **async*** with the asterisc but if I do so, then the authentication is not working.

**Clarification:**

The code does not enter the following lines:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData)
 return new Text('Loading...');
return new Text(
  snapshot.data.data['name']
 );
```

Also the `print(test);` statement prints the following:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>
```

Here is the whole part:

```
onPressed: () async {
  setState(() {
    showSpinner = true;
  });
  try {
    LoginScreen.user =
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
    if (LoginScreen.user != null) {
      // get the users data and save them
      if (LoginScreen.user.user.uid !=
          'IDVwQXAsZas213Va0OIH2IsoU5asdaTfraBJ2') {
      Widget test = await StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore
              .collection('Employees')
              .document(LoginScreen.user.user.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return new Text('Loading...');
            return new Text(
              snapshot.data.data['name']
            );
          },
        );
        print(test);
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
            context, TabCreator.screenId);
      } else {
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    // when getting an erro stop spinner
    setState(() {
      showSpinner = false;
    });
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I created a new standard flutter project in order to see if there was something else within my code that was messing the StreamBuilder. I am still getting no output.

On a side note when I am implementing the following code within the onPressed method I am getting the wanted result:

**Alternative Solution:**

```
onPressed: () {
  DocumentReference documentReference = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('Employees')
      .document('8nss0gppzNfOBMuRz9H44dv7gSd2');
  documentReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
    if (datasnapshot.exists) {
      print(datasnapshot.data['name'].toString());
    } else {
      print('Error!');
    }
});
}
```

Here is the implemented **StreamBuilder** implemented in the standard Flutter project:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              'Testing',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // DocumentReference documentReference = await Firestore.instance
          //     .collection('Employees')
          //     .document('8nss0gppzNfOBMuRz9H44dv7gSd2');
          // documentReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
          //   if (datasnapshot.exists) {
          //     print(datasnapshot.data['name'].toString());
          //   } else {
          //     print('Error!');
          //   }
          // });
          StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('Employees')
                .document('8nss0gppzNfOBMuRz9H44dv7gSd2')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Text('Loading...');
                default:
                  return new Text(snapshot.data.data['name']);
              }
            },
          );
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the issue? is this `await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);` working correctly?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, this part is working fine. The problem lies here `Widget test = await StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(...`. The code does not wait to get the data from the stream and jumps to the next page. The print gives only back the following StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> and when on debug mode, the code does not go in the code starting with `if (!snapshot.hasData)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
builder: : (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData){
              return new Text('Loading...');
          }
          else{
              print(snapshot);
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                   context, TabCreator.screenId);
           }
```

Add an `else` block so when you have data it will enter the `else` and navigate to the page.

---

Also you need to use the `StreamBuilder` inside the `build` method not inside the `onPressed` function which is used to handle data processing. Example you can do the following:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool visible = false;
  final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .document('FIJbBBiplAGorYzdtUQF')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  print(snapshot);
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    print(snapshot.data.data);
                    return new Text(snapshot.data.data["age"].toString());
                  }
                  return new CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
              visible: visible,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            visible = true;
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

So here I also use the `Visibility()` widget to hide it, but when FAB button is clicked the data from firestore will appear.

Comment: Nope, this is not it. The code does not even get to the if-else part. It just skips it.

Comment: what do u mean skips it, wat is it executing then?

Comment: When on debug it goes,  `Widget test = await StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(` then back to `onPressed: () async {` then back to `Widget test = await StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(` and then jumps out of the StreamBuilder... I have a breakpoint at the if-statement but it just ignores it. With your changes, it never jumps to the next page. It just stays at the login page.

Comment: check this  https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data to understand why you need to use the if else

Comment: what is `_firestore`? it should be a method

Comment: `final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211726/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-georgios).